# Regex Search and Replace specific text on a csv using Notepad++

Tags: csv, search, replace, notepad++

I need to do a search and replace on a csv file using regex on Notepad++ or TextPad to replace the text on a specific column if another text is met. For example, I have this line:

Search for price **50.75** only if **8x8** and **"1"** is met:

```
sample,,,,,,,,50.75,true,,,InStock,,,,,#593D24:WHITE PLASTIC,,,8x8,,,"1"" inch"
sample,,,,,,,,27.30,true,,,InStock,,,,,#593D24:WHITE PLASTIC,,,8x8,,,"2"" inch"
sample,,,,,,,,50.75,true,,,InStock,,,,,#593D24:WHITE PLASTIC,,,12x12,,,"0"" inch"
```

Replace only the price with **75.25**:

```
sample,,,,,,,,75.25,true,,,InStock,,,,,#593D24:WHITE PLASTIC,,,8x8,,,"1"" inch"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a programming language or a CSV-editing tool?

Comment: Hi InSync, surely it would be a better approach, but I've no programming skills and have already worked with simple expressions in the past. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use look arounds:

Search:

```
(?<=,)50.75(?=,.*?\b8x8\b.*?"1"")
```

Replace:

```
75.25
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/zM8cF5dmx7E9LF).

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<=,)` means the preceding char was a comma
- `(?=,.*?\b8x8\b.*?"1"")` means the following chars are a comma and later `8x8` and later `"1""`

The look behind for a comma ensures amounts like `250.75` don't match.

The word boundaries `\b` ensure dimensions like `18x8` don't match.

Using reluctant quantifier `.*?` makes it more efficient, as `.*` would consume all input to the end before backtracking to the next character.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bohemian, it worked perfectly on Notepad++, not so much on TextPad because it couldn't handle the file size, since it is a big csv file.